# Get server error response with async axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to use axios in async context.  But how do I make it so that when I get an error status (4xx/5xx) I can throw the message returned from the server instead of the standard javascript error that axios returns.

The error that the server always returns is in the format `{detail: MESSAGE}` and is a response with status 4xx/5xx.

```
const res = await axios(options).catch((err) => {
    console.error('error', err.detail);
    throw err;
});
return res.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the error to res variable, if possible, implant an error code index, determine which are 4xx or 5xx, get the detail, set the message and end with:

```js
return res.status(erros[errorCodeIndex]['status']).send(JSON.parse(`{detail: ${errors[errorCodeIndex]['message']`})}
```

if possible attribute the error code and error message JSON parse to a variable to avoid the complex line.

Commonly, I create a handleResponse function the deal with it, but you can log the error and throw a message with the details, the catch block will deal with the error response.